# Significance of low order terms in base expansion of integer square root

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My head is turning into a uniform gel of random thoughts! I cannot see a proof or find a counterexample to the following:

**Conjecture:** *Let integer $x$ be expressed as $a_3 \, b^3 + a_2 \, b^2 + a_1 \, b + a_0$ in base $b$.
If $a_3 \ge b/4$ then $\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$ is independent of $a_0$.*

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid it does depend!

Take $b=2$ and $x=8$, in which case $x=1\cdot 2^3+0\cdot 2^2+0\cdot 2+0\cdot 1$, i.e., $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$ and $a_3=1$. Clearly the condition $a_3\ge b/4$ is satisfied since  $a_3=1> b/4=1/2$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor=2$. On the other hand, if $a_0$ becomes equal to $1$, then $x$ becomes $9$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{9}\rfloor=3$.

Also try $x=3024$, with $b=10$, where $a_3=3>10/4$, $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor=54$ and $\lfloor\sqrt{x+1}\rfloor=55$.

Comment: Of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take $b=10$ and e.g. $x=3135 \ (= 56^2-1)$. Then $\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor=55$ but $\lfloor\sqrt{3136}\rfloor=56$.